# Redux state change from one component not triggering useEffect in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is first time I am using ReduxJS.

I have two components one parent and one child.

```
In child

dispatch(someAction(payload))
```

```
In Parent


let some = useSelector((state)=> state.a)


useEffect(()=>{

//some code//

},[some])
```

**Expected:**

As per my knowledge I dispacthed a action from child that will change the redux state.
Now In parent *"some"* should get updated too and it should trigger *useEffect*.

**What-is-actually-happening:**

*useEffect* Does not get triggered.

Can somebody please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does redux state actually get changed after dispatch? What does redux dev tool tell you? the code in parent component looks fine.

Comment: Is your parent component rendered on the screen when you dispatch an action from the child component?

Comment: yes @PrajwalKulkarni

Comment: Yes sate changes @spiritwalker

Comment: Is the dispatch action in the child component updating the state `a` in the store?

Comment: did you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

can you please confirm 2 things:

1. does the dispatch carry correct payload and it gets completed.
2. if the redux state is updated with the value that was dispatched.
   both of these things can be checked via Redux dev tools.

I hope your problem is related to of the two points mentioned above and yes the useEffect() should run.